# Modify main search form to search user too

Tags: search

I'm not sure if it's possible, i would like to modify the main search to allow search by user profile too...
I only found solution for separate search.

Comment: The main post loop is for posts, adding users into the mix will require a completely custom search mechanic, especially since none of the code that implements searching was built for the users table. It might be possible to create a custom post type to represent each user to search through. Eitherway this is a very non-trivial thing to implement

Comment: Thank you @TomJNowell i'gonna make another form for searching user